# Unable to send list mails to leads with email opt out unchecked

Tags: email, leads, data-protection-and-privacy

I am having problems with sending list mails. I have `Enable privacy settings` for emails. So if a `lead` has `Email Opt Out`, that `lead` will not receive the email and the sender will receive the email `This person didn't want to be emailed`.

The problem is, even if the leads have `Email Opt Out` option unchecked, I am getting the same error. Send list mail for `Contacts` with `individuals` that have `Don't Market` option unchecked is working fine. I noticed that `Email Opt Out` and `Enable privacy settings` are not connected. To make `Leads` behave like a `Contact's` `Don't Market` is my only option to create `Individuals` for `Leads`?

Answer (score 0):

The only easy way is to create an individual record for each lead and in the lead trigger set `don't market` of individual to the same value of `email opt out` of lead.